# R: Stuck on a "simple" problem: calculating total sum of squares in a n*m matrix

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, distance

Given a data matrix with n rows and m columns, I would like to calculate the total sum of squares in R.

For this I've tried a loop that iterates through the rows of each column and saves the results in a vector. These are then added to the "TSS" vector where each value is the SS of one column. The sum of this vector should be the TSS.

```
set.seed(2020)
m <- matrix(c(sample(1:100, 80)), nrow = 40, ncol = 2)

tss <- c()
for(j in 1:ncol(m)){
  tssVec <- c()
  for(i in 1:nrow(m)){
    b <- sum(((m[i,]) - mean(m[,j]))^2)
    tssVec <- c(tssVec, b)
  }
  tss <- c(tss, sum(tssVec))
}
sum(tss)
```

The output is equal to 136705.6. This is not feasible at all. As a novice coder, I am unfortunately stuck.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think it needs to be `b <- sum(((m[i,j]) - mean(m[,j]))^2)`, currently you are subtracting the mean of col j from all columns as you iterate through the rows

Comment: For such operations, try to avoid loops and instead operate on the entire matrix at once. In particular see `%*%` and friends. Here is one summary: https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/matrix.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many methods to evaluate the TSS, of course they will give you the same result. I would do something like:

Method 1 that implies the use of ANOVA:

```
n <- as.data.frame(m)
mylm <- lm(n$V1 ~ n$V2)
SSTotal <-sum(anova(mylm)[,2])
```

Method 2:

```
SSTotal <- var( m[,1] ) * (nrow(m)-1)
```